# How to valorize better offsprings better than with my roulette selection method?

Tags: genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm

I am playing around with genetic programming algorithms, and I want to know how I can valorize and make sure my best exemplares reproduce more by substituting or improving the way I choose which one will reproduce. Currently the method I use looks like this:

```
function roulette(population)
    local slice = sum_of_fitnesses(population) * math.random()
    local sum = 0
    for iter = 1, #population do
        sum = sum + population[iter].fitness
        if sum >= slice then
            return population[iter]
        end
    end
end
```

But I can't get my population to reach an average fitness which is above a certain value and I worry it's because of less fit members reproducing with more fit members and thus continuing to spread their weak genes around.

So how can I improve my roulette selection method? Or should I use a completely different fitness proportionate selector?

Comment: What is the size of the population? What is the range of the fitness values?

Comment: @user3386109 with size 100, it stops at about 0.81 with a range of 0 - 1. The crossover rate is 0.7 and the mutation rate is 0.001

Comment: I would remove the lowest 50 from the population. And for the remaining 50, make the fitness exponential, e.g. `adjusted_fitness = exp(fitness * 10)`.

Comment: @user3386109 so instead of adding each fitness for `sum_of_fitnesses` I should sum the `adjusted_fitness`es?

Comment: I guess I should have asked for the *distribution* of the fitness values. My suggestion assumes that the fitness is evenly distributed from 0.0 to 0.81, so that dropping half the population leaves fitness values from 0.40 to 0.81. If all the fitness values are bunched together say between 0.78 and 0.81, then my suggestion isn't going to work.

Comment: @user3386109 well then it won't work ahah. Though it for sure valorizes better individuals by giving them more chances.

Comment: Yup, that is the limitation of genetic algorithms. They tend to reach an equilibrium point that's reasonably good, but not quite as perfect as you might like. Kind of like real life :)

Comment: @user3386109 I can reach perfection if I increase the population though.

Comment: @user3386109 managed to get to it with the same number of individuals! I multiplied the fitness by 10 and took the third power of the result (range = 0 - 1000), and it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues at play here.

You are choosing the probability of an individual replicating based on its fitness, so the fitness function that you are using needs to exaggerate small differences or else having a minor decrease in fitness isn't so bad.  For example, if a fitness drops from 81 to 80, this change is probably within the noise of the system and won't make much of a different to evolution.  It will certainly be almost impossible to climb to a very high fitness if a series of small changes need to be made because the selective pressure simply won't be strong enough.

The way you solve this problem is by using something like tournament selection.  In it's simplest form, every time you want to choose another individual to be born, you pick K random individuals (K is known and the "tournament size").  You calculate the fitness of each individual and whomever has the highest fitness is replicated.  It doesn't matter if the fitness difference is 81 vs 80 or if its 10000 vs 2, since it simply takes the highest fitness.

Now the question is: what should you set K to?  K can be thought of as the strength of selection.  If you set it low (e.g., K=2) then many low fitness individuals will get lucky and slip through, being competed against other low-fitness individuals.  You'll get a lot of diversity, but very little section.  On the flip side, if you set K to be high (say, K=100), you're ALWAYS going to pick one of the highest fitnesses in the population, ensuring that the population average is driven closer to the max, but also driving down diversity in the population.

The particular tradeoff here depends on the specific problem.  I recommend trying out different options (including your original algorithm) with a few different problems to see what happens.  For example, try the all-ones problem: potential solutions are bit strings and a fitness is simply the number of 1's.  If you have weak selection (as in your original example, or with K=2), you'll see that it never quite gets to a perfect all-ones solution.

So, why not always use a high K?  Well consider a problem where ones are negative unless they appear in a block of four consecutive ones (or eight, or however many), when they suddenly become very positive.  Such a problem is "deceptive", which means that you need to explore through solutions that look bad in order to find ones that are good.  If you set your strength of selection too high, you'll never collect three ones for that final mutation to give you the fourth.

Lots of more advanced techniques exist that use tournament selection that you might want to look at.  For example, varying K over time, or even within  a population, select some individuals using a low K and others using a high K.  It's worth reading up on some more if you're planning to build a better algorithm.